# PHP script called twice waiting the end of previous execution

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sorry I couldn't find a better title because of my lack of vocabulary.

I have a php script answering to 2 GET parameters : one to start a long process and one to get the process progression.

Something like :

```
if(isset($_GET['start_generation'])) exit($dossier->generate());
if(isset($_GET['get_status'])) exit($dossier->getStatus());
```

A button is sending the first request (AJAX POST) and then start a timer that will check the generation status every 2 seconds using another ajax request.

Currently the first request is not ending before the generation is done, so my function to check the status will go directly from 0 to 100.

How can I close the AJAX request before calling generate() ?
Can you tell me if output buffering (ob_flush() & friends) is the way to go ?

Thanks

**Edit** (my ajax code) :

```
var lastStatus = false;
var checkDossierStatus = function(){
    $.get('".$URL."&get_status', function(status){
        status = parseInt(status, 10) || 0;
        console.log('status '+status);
        if(status === lastStatus) return false;
        lastStatus = status;

        var target;
        var activeTitleID = 0;

        switch(status){
            default:
            case 0:
                // Show something for status 0...
                break;

            case 1:
                // Show something for status 1... etc...
                break;
        }

    });
};


$('.transmission-start-btn').off('click').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('".$URL."', {transmission_action: 'start'}, function(d){
        checkDossierStatus();
        startStatusCheck();
    });
});
```

Comment: add your ajax code

Comment: Not enuff information to help here. Do you working on linux?

Comment: Ajax code added. Yes i'm on linux but does it really matter ?

Comment: You can put an additional `checkDossierStatus();` before `$.post('".$URL."', {transmission_action: 'start'}, function(d){`

Comment: The status will always be 0 at this point

Comment: The I can't understand your problem. Anyway, the naming of things is confusing `checkDossierStatus();` and `startStatusCheck();` seem similar

Comment: startStatusCheck is starting a timer that executes checkDossiersStatuts in the given interval. Maybe i'll rename it startStatusCheckInterval() then :) I think the problem is just a matter of output buffering. I'll make some tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to me was to use output buffering with a Connection: Close header and session_write_close().

```
session_write_close();  # Prevent session locking so AJAX status update request will not hang.
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Connection: Close'); # Close the ajax request.
echo 'HEY'; # This will be displayed
$size = ob_get_length();
header('Content-Length: '.$size);
ob_end_flush();
flush();

LongProcess(); # Here a can finally start a long background process
```

Answer (score 1):

You can abort Or Cancle ajax request like this

```
$(document).ready(
    var xhr;

    var fn = function(){
        if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/progress.ftl',
            success: function(data) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    };

    var interval = setInterval(fn, 500);
);
```

Comment: Thanks but i'd rather do that from PHP